# SOLR - boost a field score with boost function on another field

Tags: boost, solr, solr6

Let's say I have 4 fields: `field1`,`field2`,`field3` and `boost1` and a boost function `f`. I want to obtain a score `field1_score+field2_score*f(boost1)+field3_score*f(boost1)` which should look like `q=field1:value1 OR (field2:value2 OR field3:value3)^f(boost1)`, but Solr complains that its invalid and returns an `Lexical error`.

The current solr query look like: `defType=edismax&q=field1:value1 OR field2:value2 OR field3:value3&boost=f(boost1)`. But in this way, the value from `boost` section will also have effect on the score of `field1:value1` makes it equals to `field1_score*f(boost1)+field2_score*f(boost1)+field3_score*f(boost1)`.

I've looked around for solution for this for a while but failed to find one. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `query` function and other Solr functions to create any custom scoring you want.

For example you can do:

```
q=*:*
bf=sum(query($q1),mul(query($q2),${boost1}),mul(query($q3),${boost1}))
q1=field1:value1
q2=field2:value2
q3=field3:value3
boost1=5
```

- Of course you should set `boost1` to whatever you want